# In ELK, how to prevent filebeat grouping/clustering multiple log lines into single document?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, devops, kibana, filebeat

I am trying to index logs into elasticsearch.

To support multilines for my Java Logs, I've included the following config to my filebeat.yml. I am not sure if the grok patterns work in `filebeat`, but my requirement is that the **logs shall start with the timestamp** only!

```
filebeat.prospectors:
  - type: log
    paths:
      - /ofbiz/runtime/logs/*.log
    fields:
      docType: app-logs
    document_type: app-logs
    multiline.type: pattern
    multiline.pattern: "^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}"
    multiline.negate: true
    multiline.match: after
    ignore_older: 24h
    close_inactive: 60m

fields:
  env: dev
  project: Ofbiz-Backend

output:
  logstash:
    enabled: true
    hosts:
      - elk:5044
    timeout: 15
    ssl.enabled: false
```

But I might be missing something due to which, **batches of the expected log lines are being included in the single document**.
[image: Kibana Discovery]

My expected result is that these logs shall be indexed separately!

I've had hard luck trying all the solutions I've explored since last week, which included streaming logs directly to elastic search and using ingest pipeline, changing the configuration of `negate` and `match` to every possible combination! I couldn’t succeed!

Sample log lines are as follows:

```
2021-11-26 08:35:04,719 |OFBiz-JobQueue-0     |PersistedServiceJob           |E| PersistedServiceJob.getContext(): SAXException
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Character reference "&#55357" is an invalid XML character.
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source) ~[xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:?]
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:121) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
    at org.apache.ofbiz.base.util.UtilXml.readXmlDocument(UtilXml.java:457) ~[ofbiz.jar:?]
    at org.apache.ofbiz.base.util.UtilXml.readXmlDocument(UtilXml.java:371) ~[ofbiz.jar:?]
    at org.apache.ofbiz.entity.serialize.XmlSerializer.deserialize(XmlSerializer.java:97) ~[ofbiz.jar:?]
    at org.apache.ofbiz.service.job.PersistedServiceJob.getContext(PersistedServiceJob.java:293) [ofbiz.jar:?]
    at org.apache.ofbiz.service.job.GenericServiceJob.exec(GenericServiceJob.java:70) [ofbiz.jar:?]
    at org.apache.ofbiz.service.job.AbstractJob.run(AbstractJob.java:87) [ofbiz.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_275]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_275]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_275]
2021-11-26 08:35:04,719 |OFBiz-JobQueue-0     |PersistedServiceJob           |E| Job context is null
2021-11-26 08:35:04,719 |OFBiz-JobQueue-0     |ModelService                  |E| [ModelService.validate] : {sendProjectStatusNotification} : (IN) Required test error: org.apache.ofbiz.service.ServiceValidationException: The following required parameter is missing: [IN] [sendProjectStatusNotification.createdByPartyId]The following required parameter is missing: [IN] [sendProjectStatusNotification.projectId]The following required parameter is missing: [IN] [sendProjectStatusNotification.statusId]The following required parameter is missing: [IN] [sendProjectStatusNotification.title]The following required parameter is missing: [IN] [sendProjectStatusNotification.toRecipients]
2021-11-26 08:35:04,719 |OFBiz-JobQueue-0     |ServiceDispatcher             |E| Incoming context (in runSync : sendProjectStatusNotification) does not match expected requirements
```

Comment: The regular expressions supported by Filebeat for the `multiline.pattern` setting is explained here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/regexp-support.html (hint: no grok). [Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/multiline-examples.html#_timestamps) is explained how to capture timestamps

Comment: @Val I am able to capture the timestamp, this is not an issue for me! I've added a filter to add a field and parse it into date in the logstash config! The main issue is, the document is having multiple lines of timestamped logs! in Gist, lines starting with the timestamp should be considered as a separate document, and if the following line does not contain the timestamp, it should be considered a part of previous line!

Comment: As per elastic search docs "This example will not work correctly if start/end log blocks are mixed with non-multiline logs, or if different start/end log blocks overlap with each other. For instance, Some other log log lines in the following example will be merged into a single multiline document because they neither match multiline.pattern nor multiline.flush_pattern, and multiline.negate is set to true." Seems like I could start exploring this statement! It has something to do with negate:true .